# Return array, not object from Doctrine query - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using this:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')->findAll(array(), Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

I thought that should ensure it returns an array of an array, but it still returns an array of objects.

I need the whole result returned as an array of an array so I can do this kind of thing (silly example, but it explains what I mean):

```
<?php
$result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')->findAll('return-an-array');
?>    
This is the age of the person at the 5th record: <?php echo $result[4]['age']; ?>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to this [EntityRepository class](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L162), `findAll` don't take multiple arguments.

The code below should do what you want

```
$result = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')
               ->createQueryBuilder('e')
               ->select('e')
               ->getQuery()
               ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: i am having the same porblem and its giving me this error "Error: Class 'apb\appassBundle\Controller\Doctrine\ORM\Query' not found in controller"

Comment: Use a leading slash on `\Doctrine\ORM\Query`

Comment: thanx it was also working when i added use class and just add Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY

Answer (score 28):

You can also use the `getArrayResult()` function instead of `getResult()`. It returns an array of data instead:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT test FROM namespaceTestBundle:Test test");
$tests = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `getScalarResult()` to get an array result with objects truncated to strings.