# How can I fetch associated entities when fetching results as an array (hydrate array) via doctrine?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine

I am fetching data from the mysql database with doctrine:

```
$array = $this->em->getRepository(Documents::class)->findAll();
```

This is the output:

[image]

For my case I want to fetch an array directly, so I created a function:

```
$array = $this->em->getRepository(Documents::class)->getArray();
```

repository:

```
   public function getArray()
    {
      return   $this->getEntityManager()
               ->getRepository(Documents::class)
               ->createQueryBuilder('e')
               ->select('e')
               ->getQuery()
               ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
      }
```

The array is created, but some fields are missing:

[image]

How can I also fetch pages and products?  And I would like my data to be shown as a date `+"timestamp": "02.12.2019"`

Comment: And what's the problem with returning array of objects?

Comment: its because I later need an array because I build an array with some other arrays together with this array. And if I can fetch the array directly the performance is much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot about core class that will require another setup

Just use `getArrayResult()` function instead of `getResult()`. It returns an array of all data

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT test FROM namespaceTestBundle:Test test");
$tests = $query->getArrayResult();
```

> Query#getResult(): Retrieves a collection of objects. The result is
>   either a plain collection of objects (pure) or an array where the
>   objects are nested in the result rows (mixed).
>
> Query#getArrayResult(): Retrieves an array graph (a nested array) that
>   is largely interchangeable with the object graph generated by
>   Query#getResult() for read-only purposes.

I Just tested that returns all result of data as an array nested:

Second soluton in other answer will work as well but they works different ways:

Also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17499629/12232340 And repository

According to this [EntityRepository class](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L162), `findAll` don't take multiple arguments.

Comment: I tested ArrayResult but still the output is only `0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 167
    "uuid" => "086aa56ed3"
    "name" => "Hauptordner"
    "timestamp" => DateTime @1575285037 {#57472 …1}
  ]`

Comment: Now persistent collections are added to the array

Comment: Talk to me simple I am not english and google doesnt translate well :) Do you get full array ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a "fetch-join" by adding it to the select:

```php
public function getArray()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository(Documents::class)
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->select('e', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('e.products', 'p')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

More info: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Comment: It works! Thank you! One more question, this is the output of your code `"products" => array:9 [ …9]` is there a way to catch directly the id of the product? `"products" => 2"`?

Comment: This was my idea `->leftJoin('e.products.id','p')`  but this is not working

Comment: your suggestion does not work with the persistent collection, so it works only with pages, but not with products

Comment: I think This flats array and doesn't add children and parent from entity. `getArrayResult()` is alias of `getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);`

Comment: @Dilek I do not understand exactly what you mean

Comment: search for diff between `HYDRATE_ARRAY` and `HYDRATE_ARRAY_HIERARCHY` İf you have core class installed you could query like this  : `public function findAllArray()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY_HIERARCHY);
}`

Comment: @Dilek This sounds interesting. Just tested it, but I get an error `Attempted to load class "Doctrine_Core" from namespace "App\Repository".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?`

Comment: @fala check this page has all you want : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/data-hydrators.html